# Python Queue not pulling thread objects in order. Only working on last thread which never ends

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, python-multithreading

When running my code, the "Teller" threads help the same "Customer" thread over and over again until an undetermined amount of times. I don't understand why the last customer created gets helped over and over though the other threads were created.

I am unsure if a .join() is necessary somewhere in the code for the Customer threads. I have placed it in multiple places in the code and my code seems to get stuck.

```
from threading import Semaphore, Thread, Lock
from queue import Queue, Empty
from random import randint
from time import sleep

max_customers_in_bank = 10
'''maximum number of customers that can be in
the bank at one time'''
max_customers = 7  # number of customers that will go to the bank today
max_tellers = 2  # number of tellers working today
teller_timeout = 10  # longest time that a teller will wait for new customers


# Part I
class Customer:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return {self.name}


class Teller:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return {self.name}


def bankprint(lock, msg):
    # Print message with a context manager lock
    with lock:
        print(msg)


def wait_outside_bank(customer, guard, teller_line, printlock):
    # Call bankprint and format customer object string approiately for call
    bankprint(printlock, ("(C) '" + customer.name + "' waiting outside bank"))
    # Create semphore for max customers and aquire it
    guard.acquire()
    bankprint(printlock,
              ("<G> Security guard letting '" +
               customer.name + "' into the bank"))
    bankprint(printlock, ("(C) '" + customer.name + "' getting into line"))
    # Create teller line queue and put custiomers into queue
    teller_line.put(customer)
    
    


# Part III
def teller_job(teller, guard, teller_line, printlock):
    bankprint(printlock, ("[T] '" + teller.name + "' starting work"))
    while True:
        try:
            teller_line.get(timeout=teller_timeout)
            bankprint(printlock, ("[T] '" + teller.name + "' is now helping" +
                                  customer.name))
            sleep(randint(1, 4))
            bankprint(printlock, ("[T] '" + teller.name + "' is done helping" +
                                  customer.name))
            bankprint(printlock, ("<G> Security guard letting '" +
                                  customer.name + "' out of the bank"))
            guard.release()
        except Empty:
            bankprint(printlock, ("[T] Nobody is in line, '" + teller.name +
                                  "' is going on break"))
            break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    printlock = Lock()
    teller_line = Queue(maxsize=max_customers_in_bank)
    guard = Semaphore(max_customers_in_bank)
    Customer_List = [Customer("Customer_"+str(i)) for i in
                     range(1, max_customers+1)]
    for customer in Customer_List:
        thread = Thread(target=wait_outside_bank,
                        args=(customer, guard, teller_line, printlock))
        thread.start()
    sleep(5)
    print("*B* Tellers starting work")
    Teller_List = [Teller("Teller_"+str(i)) for i in range(1, max_tellers+1)]
    Teller_Threads = [Thread(target = teller_job, args = (teller, guard, teller_line, printlock)) for teller in Teller_List]
    for teller in Teller_Threads: 
        teller.start()

    for teller in Teller_Threads:
        teller.join()
    print("*B* Bank closed")
```

Sample Output:

```
(C) 'Customer_1' waiting outside bank
<G> Security guard letting 'Customer_1' into the bank
(C) 'Customer_1' getting into line
(C) 'Customer_2' waiting outside bank
(C) 'Customer_3' waiting outside bank
<G> Security guard letting 'Customer_2' into the bank
(C) 'Customer_4' waiting outside bank
<G> Security guard letting 'Customer_3' into the bank
(C) 'Customer_3' getting into line
(C) 'Customer_2' getting into line
(C) 'Customer_6' waiting outside bank
<G> Security guard letting 'Customer_4' into the bank
(C) 'Customer_4' getting into line
(C) 'Customer_7' waiting outside bank
<G> Security guard letting 'Customer_6' into the bank
(C) 'Customer_5' waiting outside bank
<G> Security guard letting 'Customer_7' into the bank
(C) 'Customer_7' getting into line
<G> Security guard letting 'Customer_5' into the bank
(C) 'Customer_5' getting into line
(C) 'Customer_6' getting into line
*B* Tellers starting work
[T] 'Teller_1' starting work
[T] 'Teller_1' is now helpingCustomer_7
[T] 'Teller_2' starting work
[T] 'Teller_2' is now helpingCustomer_7
[T] 'Teller_1' is done helpingCustomer_7
<G> Security guard letting 'Customer_7' out of the bank
[T] 'Teller_1' is now helpingCustomer_7
[T] 'Teller_2' is done helpingCustomer_7
<G> Security guard letting 'Customer_7' out of the bank
[T] 'Teller_2' is now helpingCustomer_7
[T] 'Teller_1' is done helpingCustomer_7
[T] 'Teller_2' is done helpingCustomer_7
<G> Security guard letting 'Customer_7' out of the bank
<G> Security guard letting 'Customer_7' out of the bank
[T] 'Teller_1' is now helpingCustomer_7
[T] 'Teller_2' is now helpingCustomer_7
[T] 'Teller_1' is done helpingCustomer_7
<G> Security guard letting 'Customer_7' out of the bank
[T] 'Teller_1' is now helpingCustomer_7
[T] 'Teller_2' is done helpingCustomer_7
<G> Security guard letting 'Customer_7' out of the bank
[T] 'Teller_1' is done helpingCustomer_7
<G> Security guard letting 'Customer_7' out of the bank
[T] Nobody is in line, 'Teller_2' is going on break
[T] Nobody is in line, 'Teller_1' is going on break
*B* Bank closed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`teller_job` does not define `customer` so when you use `customer.name`, you use the `customer` in the global namespace. It was assigned in the for loop `for customer in Customer_List:` and that loop has finished (leaving the last customer in the list as it last value) before the threads do the processing.

Comment: Thank you, I assigned my queue .get() to a variable and accessed the name through the variable. This got it working properly.